# Constructing a counterexample to: if $\lim_nf(an)= 0$ for every $a>0$ then $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$ exists.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $f$ be a real valued function defined on $[0,\infty)$ such that $\lim_nf(an)=0$ for every $a>0$. Then, $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$ exists.

I'm trying to construct a counterexample to the statement above but I couldn't come up with any counterexample. So I looked at the solution and the the following counterexample was given:

$f(x)=\begin{cases} 1; x=n 2^\frac 1n\: \forall n\in \mathbb N\\ 0; \text{else}\end{cases}$

I understand that this works because there are unique $k,j\in \mathbb N$ such that $ak=j2^\frac 1j$ (for if there are $k',j'$ such that the ordered pair $(k,j)\ne (k',j')$ and that $ak'=j'2^{\frac 1{j'}}$ then $2^r$ turns out to be a rational number for some $r\in (0,1)\cap \mathbb Q$). And that's the problem. I don't yet know $2^r$ is irrational for every rational in $(0,1)$. I understand that $2^\frac 1n$ is irrational for every $n\ge 2$ but then the fact that $2^{\frac mn}=(2^\frac 1n)^m$ could possibly be rational, worries me.

So is there any example which doesn't use this fact ($2^r$ is irrational for every rational $r\in (0,1)$)? How do I construct such example (preferably using $\sin,\cos,\log$ etc.)?

Thanks.

Comment: To understand the point you are missing, [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Integer_to_Rational_Power_is_Irrational_iff_not_Integer_or_Reciprocal) can help.

Comment: I dare conjecture that no “sin, cos, log etc.” (aka. elementary) counterexample exists.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen There is no counterexample with $f$ right-continuous (Croft−Kingman lemma).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us use only the fact that an irrational number $\beta$ **exists**. For this define $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&x-\beta\in\Bbb Q\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
Then for each $a>0$, at most one $f(na)$ is non-zero. Indeed, if $na=r+\beta$ and $ma=s+\beta$ with $n\ne m$, then $mr+m\beta=man=ns+n\beta$ and $\beta=\frac{mr-ns}{n-m}\in \Bbb Q$, contradiction. Hence $f(na)\to0$, whereas $f(x)=1$ on a dense set.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand this :).

Answer (score 2):

This is not an explict construction but I hope you are interested in this. By induction  we can find a sequence $(x_n)$ increasing to $\infty$ such that $\frac {x_n} {x_i}$ is irrational for $1 \leq i < n, (n \geq 1)$. [Use the fact that $\mathbb Q$ is countable and $\mathbb R$ is uncountable]  Let $f(x)=1$ if $x \in \{x_1,x_2,\cdots\}$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. This $f$ has the desired properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot :). So $(na)$ can't be a subsequence of $(x_n)$. That is, $(x_n)$ can have atmost finitely many terms of $(na)$ that is for large $n$, we'll have $f(na)=0$ but clearly $\lim f(x_n)=1$ so  this works. Unfortunately, I can accept at most one answer. :)